# Mysql Trigger update another table's quantity by 1

Tags: mysql

Hi I'm trying to create a trigger that adds 1 to the quantity of insert's id in a helper table holding the codes for the id's. Here are my 2 tables.

```
     Animal
   ----------
   AnimalId
   Breedcode

   Breed_codes
  ------------
   Breedcode
   breed
   Quantity

     CREATE TRIGGER `updater` AFTER INSERT ON `Animal`
     FOR EACH ROW UPDATE breed_codes
     SET Quantity = Quantity + 1
     WHERE Breedcode = Animal.Breedcode
```

However it states that the Animal Breed code isn't found. Can anyone please help me fix my trigger. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your UPDATE query you can use:

1. Column names from the table(s) you are updating,
2. Column names from the table you define trigger for with NEW.column (insert and update triggers) or OLD.column (update and delete triggers).

In your case instead of `Animal.Breedcode` you should use `New.Breedcode`.